# SASL Authentication Exception while connecting to openfire XMPP IOS

Tags: openfire, xmppframework, xcode6.1, ios8.1, sasl

> I'm working on a chat app where we need instant messaging with `XMPP`.
>   While logging in to app, I'm able to authenticate user with `OpenFire`.
>   But, in `OpenFire logs`, I see this

```
org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthorizationManager - AuthorizationManager: Trying Default Mapping.map(deep) 
2015.01.17 12:39:05 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthorizationMapping - DefaultAuthorizationMapping: No realm found 
2015.01.17 12:39:05 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthorizationManager - AuthorizationManager: Trying Default Policy.authorize(deep , deep) 
2015.01.17 12:39:05 org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthorizationPolicy - DefaultAuthorizationPolicy: Checking authenID realm
```

> I'm not getting what kind of warning this is. But it seems like `SASL`
>   `authentication`. And in app, Second time If I try connecting `XMPP` with
>   `Openfire` again, I got this in openfire logs

```
 2015.01.17 12:43:10 org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SASLAuthentication - SASLAuthentication: SaslException 
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: digest response format violation. Mismatched response. 
at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Server.validateClientResponse(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.security.sasl.digest.DigestMD5Server.evaluateResponse(Unknown Source) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SASLAuthentication.handle(SASLAuthentication.java:368) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.process(StanzaHandler.java:176) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler.messageReceived(ConnectionHandler.java:181)
```

> Cause of these warnings, I'm unable to perform `Send friend request` functionality
>   of `XMPP`.I'm totally confused how to get rid of this kind of warnings.
>   As in `android` ,we can disable/enable `SASLAuthentication`. Is there any
>   way to disable in `IOS`. or if there's any other way to solve these
>   issues. Also,logged in user is not showing online in `openfire`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.